# Can’t pass the answers in replit with gdb from a text file

Tags: gdb, replit

I get this error from trying to input the answer files as a text document in replit using gdb, how do I solve this?

```
Error: Couldn't open answers. txt
[Inferior 1 (process 42) exited with code 010]
```

There are no answers online.

Comment: You are trying to use `answers .txt` (with a space in it). Do you actually have a file with a space in its name?